# Django - how to show all formset value on the page

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the form that looks like this:

```
class ItemForm(forms.Form):
    item = forms.IntegerField()
```

And this is view for my form:

```
def testform(request):
  item_form = formset_factory(ItemForm, extra=2)
    if request.method == 'POST':
      item_formset = item_form(request.POST, prefix='items')
        if item_formset.is_valid():
          for items in item_formset:
            cd = items.cleaned_data
            item = cd.get('item')
          return render(request, 'testform/result.html', {'item_formset':item_formset})
     else:
       item_formset = item_form(prefix='items')
     return render(request, 'testform/index.html', {'item_formset':item_formset})
```

Here is my result.html:

```
{% for i in cd %}
        {{item}}
{% endfor%}
```

On `result.html` page i want to show all values of `item` formset that input on form page. But I've got just clean page.
What i'm doing wrong. Thanks for your help

Comment: What is `item` ? your iteration loop has `i` and you do `{{item}}`

Comment: I thought that `item` is `item = forms.IntegerField() `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over your formset, which you're passing to your `render` method as 'item_formset'. So your `result.html` should look like:

```
{% for item_form in item_formset %}
    {{ item_form.item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Notice you'll be accessing the `item` field on each formset form, just as you would in a normal form.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each element in form set or display the entire formset at a time. You can find it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform